# <ion-tab title> update angularjs

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Is there a way to update title of ion-tab using angular syntax?

I have already tried title="{{Account}}"

```
<ion-tab id="tabSettings" title="Account" icon-off="ion-settings" icon-on="ion-settings" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

Here is the codepen link :
http://codepen.io/TimothyKrell/pen/bnukj

Comment: could you add codepen/plunkr?

Comment: http://codepen.io/TimothyKrell/pen/bnukj

Comment: i want to set title programmatically

Answer (score 4):

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sO8aUa?p=preview)

The title of an ion-tab can dynamically updated by using angular two way binding synatx.

**Tabs.html**

```
<ion-tab title="{{tab1Title}}" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
</ion-tab>
```

**tabCtrl.js**

```
app.controller('TabsCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.tab1Title="Home";
});
```

Comment: thank you ver much ! now it works , i was missing the controller